# Python peer to peer, socket

Tags: python, sockets

I've been building a simple client/server application, but the server seem redundant as I only use the server to pass information to another client. So instead I'd like to go with a peer to peer instead.

Would it be possible for both peers to have a socket open and constantly listen while also be able to dynamically send to the othe peer?

peer 1

```
def receive():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5002

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data)
            c.send(bytes("Ordre registreret", "utf-8"))
        c.close()

def send():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5001

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((self.host, self.port))

    s.send("Test", "utf-8")

    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = str(data, "utf-8")
    s.close()
```

peer 2

```
def receive():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5001

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data)
            c.send(bytes("Ordre registreret", "utf-8"))
        c.close()

def send():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5002

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((self.host, self.port))

    s.send("Test", "utf-8")

    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = str(data, "utf-8")
    s.close()
```

So basically two nearly identical peers, but different ports for binding and connect. Can the host be the same tho? Also if this way is possible would I have to use threads to allow other functionality as the receive method would be in a infinite loop listening?

Comment: _listen while also be able to dynamically send_ - on which occasions do you need to send?